# Passing parameters to Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I'm having issues passing parameters to `Invoke-Command`, I've tried using `-Args` and `-ArgumentList` to no avail.

```
function One {
 $errcode = $args
 $username = "Ron"
 $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Baxter" -AsPlainText -Force
 $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
 $cred
 $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyPc -ScriptBlock { & cmd.exe /c "C:\Scripts\test.bat" Param1 $errcode ; $lastexitcode}  -Credential $cred
 echo $result
}


One 10
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Not as such, all that gets returned is 'ECHO is on.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your function to pass in your parameter as `$errcode` rather than using `$args`, this is better code as it's less confusing. (I'd recommend readng up on [parameters and functions](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/04/07/powershell-functions-with-parameters.aspx) as it'll certainly help)

Then you need to pass `$errcode` into `Invoke-Command` using the `ArgumentList` parameter, and use `$args[0]` in its place:

```
function One ($errcode) {
    $username = "Ron"
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Baxter" -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

    $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyPc -ScriptBlock { & cmd.exe /c "C:\Scripts\test.bat" Param1 $args[0] ; $lastexitcode} -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $errcode
    echo $Result
}
One 10
```

Comment: Oh my! That sir is delightful. Thank you. Works an absolute treat.